# Angular Material basic alignment, size, float utility class

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When it goes beyond the material components [material.angular.io](http://material.angular.io), say if I just want to do simple `text-align: right` or `float:right` in a `<div>`. How can I do that?

I have seen

```
align="end"
```

in some material widgets being used. But it is not working for all widgets.

And there is

```
matLine
```

directive which will make element the whole line in a list

I sorta remember seeing

```
matSize="large"
```

or something like that somewhere.

But I couldn't find anything related to this from the official documentation. For me, this is no brainer.

For example, in `bootstrap 3`, there is

```
 <div class="text-right">
 <div class="pull-right">
```

helper classes. `Bootstrap 4` even has more fine-grained classes for adjusting padding and margin `m-2` `p-2` etc.

Also to resize for smaller, larger elements ( button, input etc.)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

Is there any solution to handle this in Angular Material at all?

Or really it's all about widgets. You just have to tackle those details yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Angular Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) is created for this. Your example could be created like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="flex-end"></div>
```

The project is still in beta though (for a long time now) and I'm not quite sure how actively it is maintained.

Button sizing is not available in the material specs, so you have to implement those yourself.